# Почему происходит ошибка чтения json файла при запуске реального apk файла?

Tags: json, libgdx, apk

**Приложение libgdx работает везде, кроме apk файла на андройде. Судя по исключению эта ошибка связана с json файлом.**
**"jsons/button" - json файл**

```
{
  com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color: {
    white: { a: 1, b: 1, g: 1, r: 1 },
    red: { a: 1, b: 0, g: 0, r: 1 },
    black: { a: 1, b: 0, g: 0, r: 0 }
  },
  com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton$TextButtonStyle: {
    default: { down: fontgray, up: fontblack, font: arial, fontColor: white },
    toggle: { down: fontgreen, up: fontblack, checked: fontgreen, font: arial, fontColor: white },
    settings: { down: fontgray, up: fontbrown, font: arial, fontColor: white },
    closed: { down: downclosed, up: upclosed, font: arial, fontColor: white }
  },
  com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ImageButton$ImageButtonStyle: {
    menu: { down: downmenu, up: upmenu },
    replay: { down: downarrow, up: uparrow },
    back: { down: downbackarrow, up: upbackarrow },
    info: { down: downfigure, up: upfigure }
  }
}
```

Когда я запускаю libgdx приложение на desktop, эмуляторе, по usb на реальном устройстве - всё хорошо, не возникает никаких ошибок. Когда я собрал apk файл и запустил его на реальном устройстве, то приложение сразу же рушится. Мне удалось получить исключение этой проблемы:

**com.badlogic.gdx.utils.f0: Error reading file: jsons/button.json**

Шрифт "arial" добавляется таким образом:

```
buttonSkin = new Skin();
buttonSkin.addRegions(gdxGame.getChessAtlas());
buttonSkin.add("arial", Settings.FONT.getArial());
buttonSkin.load(Gdx.files.internal("jsons/button.json"));
```

Это необходимо, так как ttf шрифт преобразуется в Bitmap в другом месте. В любом случае всё хорошо работает везде, кроме apk файла.

Answer (score 0):

Это связано с тем, что libgdx не умеет нормально работать на Android. Этот вывод можно сделать, так как в коде ошибок нет. libgdx не умеет нормально работать на Android, так как эта платформа очень костыльная и способна поддерживать только свои собственные костыли.